# Outsourcing a freelancing project

Tags: contracts, attracting-clients, working-from-home, business-plan, freelance

I'm interested to do freelancing in Hardware designing to upskill myself and also financial growth. As I'm a beginner, how to seeking and approach a first client and what's the initial step to do freelancing?

Comment: This question needs a location tag as the process might be different in various countries.